# ¿Renombrar archivo sin cambiar ubicación con C#?

Tags: c#

Quiero renombrar archivos con C# pero cuando lo realizo me copia el archivo a la carpeta debug y lo que quiero es renombrar el archivo pero que quede en la misma ubicación.

El archivo a renombrar lo selecciono mediante un `OpenFileDialog` y guardo la ruta completa en la variable `ImageInfo.FilePath`

```
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(ImageInfo.FilePath);
string nombreNuevo "PD0102.tif"
File.Move(fullPath, nombreNuevo);
```

**Ejemplo**

Selecciono el archivo en la ruta: `"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\imagen.tif"`

Al renombrar lo guarda en `"C:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Archivos\bin\Debug\PD0102.tif"`.

Como lo necesito: `"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\PD0102.tif"`

*Hay que tener en cuenta que la ruta de cada archivo es dinámica ya que se selecciona mediante `OpenFileDialog`.*

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cambie el nombre y se quede en la dirección original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al especificar el nombre del archivo destino sin la ruta, es interpretado como una ruta relativa a la carpeta donde está la aplicación.

Para resolverlo, debes construir el nuevo nombre combinandolo con la carpeta origen de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(ImageInfo.FilePath);

    //Con esta instrucción obtienes la ruta donde está el archivo origen
    string soloRuta = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);

    //Con esta instrucción combinas la ruta de origen con el nuevo nombre de archivo
    string nombreNuevo = Path.Combine(soloRuta,"PD0102.tif");

    File.Move(fullPath, nombreNuevo);
}
```

Comment: Excelente así quedó bien, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo pone en el Debug porque no le estás dando la ruta completa. Deberías hacer algo como esto.

```
   var dirDst = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
   var fileDst = Path.Combine(dirDst,"PD0102.tif");
   File.Move(fullPath,fileDst);
```

Ahora todo lo puedes poner en una sola linea pero no se verá la intención.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar dos cosas:

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;


 class RenameFile
 {
     static void Main()
     {
         string antes = "D:\myfolder\myfile.txt";
         string despues = "D:\myfolder\mynewfile.txt";
         System.IO.File.Move(antes, despues);
     }
 }
```

El archivo debe existir en el directorio especificado. Si no existe, entonces la función arrojará el error `FileNotFoundException`.

O puedes usar esto:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class RenameFile
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string antes = @"D:\oldfile.txt";
        string despues = @"D:\newfile.txt";
        File.Copy(antes, despues);
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por el dato, solo que como comento, el archivo lo selecciono mediante `OpenFileDialog` por lo cual la ruta es dinámica.